# OpenShift Tomcat Servlets 404 Not Found

Tags: java

I have transferred a working Tomcat application from a previous Tomcat6 hosting server, with ready compiled servlet class files that were successfully tested on my pc’s localhost / Tomcat Server.

I have successfully deployed this previously working application on OpenShift, without any errors whatsoever – see screen report for the deployment below.

However, not a single servlet can be found when I attempt to run the application – only html / shtml files can be found and run successfully.

The example screen error is as follows:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /servlet/scriptLocating.TourScriptsServlet_
**type** Status report 
**message** /servlet/scriptLocating.TourScriptsServlet_
**description** The requested resource is not available.
________________________________________
Apache Tomcat/6.0.41
```

My application is deployed on OpenShift as ROOT.war  -- and the following screen report for the deployment  process on ‘git push’  shows BUILD SUCCESS and deployment status: success.

I am new to OpenShift and am at a complete loss as to what to try next to resolve this problem – it is an existential threat to my application, as it cannot run without servlets working.

I have tried the following solutions that apparently worked for other developers on this forum with this 404 Not Found problem on OpenShift, but I have had no success:

1. I have checked, and the .openshift directory does exist and contains the empty /markers/java7 file;
2. I have checked, the OpenShift build / deployment process has used Java7 (and NOT Java6), for projects with Servlet 3.0 needed – although the JBoss EWS 1.0 cartridge installed in my application is Tomcat6;
3. I have changed the Application directory, from ‘main’ to ‘mainApp,’ just in case there was a conflict with /src/’main’ for OpenShift resources.

I am getting desperate and would be most grateful for any advice anyone on this forum can offer.

### Thank you

```
C:\Users\User\Documents\Iwapdb_OpenShift\projects\main>git push
Counting objects: 4089, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2908/2908), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4089/4089), 90.12 MiB | 56.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 4089 (delta 982), reused 4051 (delta 965)
remote: Stopping jbossews cartridge
remote: Sending SIGTERM to jboss:316994 ...
remote: Stopping MySQL 5.5 cartridge
remote: Stopping PHPMyAdmin cartridge
remote: Waiting for stop to finish
remote: Waiting for stop to finish
remote: Building git ref 'master', commit 43bf513
remote: Using Maven mirror /var/lib/openshift/5650cdc11d5181cae000001f/app-   root/
runtime/repo//.openshift/config/settings.rhcloud.xml
remote: Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232336; 2012-12-18 14:36:37-0500)
remote: Maven home: /usr/share/java/apache-maven-3.0.4
remote: Java version: 1.7.0_99, vendor: Oracle Corporation
remote: Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.99/jre
remote: Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: ANSI_X3.4-1968
remote: OS name: "linux", version: "2.6.32-573.12.1.el6.x86_64", arch: "i386", f
amily: "unix"
remote: Found pom.xml... attempting to build with 'mvn --global-settings /var/lib/openshift/5650cdc11d5181cae000001f/approot/runtime/repo//.openshift/config/settings.rhcloud.xml clean package -Popenshift -DskipTests'
remote: [INFO] Scanning for projects...
remote: [INFO]

remote: [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
remote: [INFO] Building main 1.0
remote: [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
remote: [INFO]
remote: [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ main ---
remote: [INFO]
remote: [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ main ---
remote: [debug] execute contextualize
remote: [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
remote: [INFO] Copying 1 resource
remote: [INFO]
```

### remote: [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ main

```
remote: [INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
remote: [INFO]
remote: [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default testResources) @ main ---
remote: [debug] execute contextualize
remote: [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
remote: [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /var/lib/openshift/5650cdc11d5181cae000001f/approot/runtime/repo/src/test/resources
remote: [INFO]
remote: [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile)@ main ---
remote: [INFO] No sources to compile
remote: [INFO]
remote: [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @ main ---
remote: [INFO] Tests are skipped.
remote: [INFO]
remote: [INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war (default-war) @ main ---
remote: [INFO] Packaging webapp
remote: [INFO] Assembling webapp [main] in [/var/lib/openshift/5650cdc11d5181cae000001f/app-root/runtime/repo/target/main]
remote: [INFO] Processing war project
remote: [INFO] Copying webapp resources [/var/lib/openshift/5650cdc11d5181cae000001f/approot/runtime/repo/src/main/webapp]
remote: [INFO] Webapp assembled in [10484 msecs]
remote: [INFO] Building war:/var/lib/openshift/5650cdc11d5181cae000001f/app-root/runtime/repo/webapps/ROOT.war
remote: [INFO] WEB-INF/web.xml already added, skipping
remote: [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
remote: [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
remote: [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
-------
remote: [INFO] Total time: 34.996s
remote: [INFO] Finished at: Thu Apr 21 18:20:53 EDT 2016
remote: [INFO] Final Memory: 8M/161M
remote: [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
-------
remote: Preparing build for deployment
remote: Deployment id is 62d4bfcd
remote: Activating deployment
remote: Starting MySQL 5.5 cartridge
remote: Starting PHPMyAdmin cartridge
remote: Starting jbossews cartridge
remote: Found 127.9.135.129:8080 listening port
remote: -------------------------
remote: Git Post-Receive Result: success
remote: Activation status: success
remote: Deployment completed with status: success
To ssh://5650cdc11d5181cae000001f@main-iwapdb.rhcloud.com/~/git/main.git
```

e707aa1..43bf513  master -> master

```
C:\Users\User\Documents\Iwapdb_OpenShift\projects\main>rhc app show main --gears quota
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
RSA 1024 bit CA certificates are loaded due to old openssl compatibility
Gear                     Cartridges                            Used  Limit
------------------------ ----------------------------------- ------ ------
5650cdc11d5181cae000001f jbossews-1.0 mysql-5.5 phpmyadmin-4 1.8 GB 3.2 GB
============================================================================
```